# Transform to long format from a adjacent matrix(from-to) format data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following adjacent table which I want to convert into a long format.

```
ID <- c(rep('A',1), rep('B',3))
From <- c('Category_8', 'Category_3', 'Category_4', 'Category_1')
To <- c('Category_1', 'Category_4', 'Category_1', 'Category_3')

have <- tibble(
  ID,
  From,
  To
)
have
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  ID    From       To        
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     
1 A     Category_8 Category_1
2 B     Category_3 Category_4
3 B     Category_4 Category_1
4 B     Category_1 Category_3
```

```
ID <- c(rep('A',2), rep('B',4))
process <- c('Category_8', 'Category_1', 'Category_3', 'Category_4', 'Category_1','Category_3')

want <- tibble(
  ID,
  process
)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  ID    process   
  <chr> <chr>     
1 A     Category_8
2 A     Category_1
3 B     Category_3
4 B     Category_4
5 B     Category_1
6 B     Category_3
```

My attempt is as below

```
have %>%
  pivot_longer(!ID, names_to = "x", values_to = "process") %>% dplyr::select(-x)

# A tibble: 8 x 2
  ID    process   
  <chr> <chr>     
1 A     Category_8
2 A     Category_1
3 B     Category_3
4 B     Category_4
5 B     Category_4
6 B     Category_1
7 B     Category_1
8 B     Category_3
```

Notice that row 4 and 5, and row 6 and 7 are essentially duplicates. If were to chain the above operation with `unique()`, this solves the duplication, but I will lose out the last row because `unique()` will treat row 3 and and 8 as duplicates when it should not.

There's another column which I have omitted here which is the time. I wonder whether if I can include that column, it can solves this.

Comment: Because the process can go back to a previous category. For example the ID B, it may have started with Cat 3, passed to another processes (Cat 4 and Cat 1) but ends with Cat 3.

Comment: Another example, let's say there's ID C, it starts with Cat 1, passed to Cat 2 and bounce back to Cat 1, etc. The expectation is to have `Cat 1-> Cat 2 -> Cat1 -> Cat2`, etc. If I remove duplications by just using ID and process column, I won't get the whole transactions or processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating run-length encoding after your syntax will solve the problem

```
library(data.table) #for rleid() function
have %>%
  pivot_longer(!ID, names_to = "x", values_to = "process") %>% select(-x) %>%
  mutate(d = rleid(ID, process)) %>%
  unique() %>% select(-d)
  ID    process   
  <chr> <chr>     
1 A     Category_8
2 A     Category_1
3 B     Category_3
4 B     Category_4
5 B     Category_1
6 B     Category_3
```

Comment: great function, have never used it before, thanks @AnilGoyal

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a logical filter with the help of `lag()`.

```
library(tidyverse) 
enter code here
have %>%
    pivot_longer(!ID, names_to = "x", values_to = "process") %>% dplyr::select(-x) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(previous = lag(process)) %>% # Create a variable that holds the value from the previous row.
    replace_na(list(previous = "---")) %>% # This inputs some text into first observations, as to remove the NA and enable a comaprison.
    filter(process != previous) %>% # Filter out those cases wher the previous value and the current value are the same.
    select(-previous)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID    process   
  <chr> <chr>     
1 A     Category_8
2 A     Category_1
3 B     Category_3
4 B     Category_4
5 B     Category_1
6 B     Category_3
```

Comment: Nice thought flow. At first I don't follow, but when I try step by step, I understand what it does :)